Which conditions identify whether belief centralization should be viewed in light of its contribution to explanatory scope or hedgehogishness?
Building on Isaah Berlin's The Hedgehog and the Fox, "Superforeaster" research suggests that one of the factors most strongly correlated to an individual's ability to make correct predictions is thinking on the fox side of the spectrum.  Part of this foxiness is a disposition toward prioritizing decentralized noetic structure higher than centralized, overarching theories or ideology.  This may even be a common notion in colloquial contexts, as per the man with a hammer parable, or phrases like "you always think every problem is caused by immigrants."
However, explanatory scope is generally taken to be among the most commonly accepted criteria for a good explanation.  Explanatory scope is high when fewer overarching theories explain more things, but when those theories, things, and their explanatory relations are believed, hedgehogishness ensues almost by definition.  Even if not mutually exclusive by precise definition, I am often at a loss for whether to treat a particular instance of noetic structure centralization as an epistemic benefit or cost.
Consider the example of Alice, who believes the following arguments...
The College Argument

The government should provide the resources necessary to attend college to every citizen.
If the government provides the resources necessary to attend college, then it is better to provide Universal Basic Income than college vouchers, because the former preserves for the individual more freedom over expenditure decisions, and because some citizens may find goods they value even more than college.



Therefore, the government should provide Universal Basic Income to every citizen.

The Food Stamp Argument

The government should provide the resources necessary to purchase Quantity X of Food Stamp approved food items to every citizen.
If the government provides the resources necessary to purchase Quantity X of Food Stamp approved food items, then it is better to provide Universal Basic Income than Food Stamps, because the former preserves for the individual more freedom over expenditure decisions, and because some citizens may find goods they value even more than Food Stamp approved food items.



Therefore, the government should provide Universal Basic Income to every citizen.

The Shelter Argument

The government should provide the resources necessary to afford shelter to every citizen.
If the government provides the resources necessary to afford shelter, then it is better to provide Universal Basic Income than buildings, because the former preserves for the individual more freedom over expenditure decisions, and because some citizens may find goods they value even more than the building they would be assigned.



Therefore, the government should provide Universal Basic Income to every citizen.

If Alice is accused of being a lady with a hammer, or "always thinking Universal Basic Income is the solution to every problem," is she obligated to accept that the relative centralization in her noetic structure is a cost, or may she reply that Universal Basic Income is a better explanation, in light of its greater explanatory scope, than it would be if it only explained how to fix fewer societal problems, and was conjoined with other explanations of how to fix the rest?
My own thought was that perhaps centralization in the noetic structure is an epistemic harm insofar as it correlates beliefs in a way that future belief revision is likely to overturn all at once a large number of beliefs or arguments relating them.  However, this criteria would probably be too impractical without some way to model the space of all possible refutations.  In the above example, more powerful arguments for the conclusion that the government should not provide Universal Basic Income to every citizen would overturn The College Argument, The Food Stamp Argument, and The Shelter Argument all at once, but it is not feasible to say in advance whether a refutation of 1 would also affect 4 and/or 7.  This thought also treats unfalsifiability as an epistemic benefit, which is non-standard.

@local Can you elaborate a bit?  I don't quite understand what you're asking.

I'm not personally claiming that hedgehogishness is epistemcially better than foxiness, just that valuing explanatory scope seems to lean heavily in that direction.

Gowers describes a similar dichotomy in The Two Cultures of Mathematics which he terms theory-builders vs problem-solvers, adding:"It is obvious that mathematics needs both sorts of mathematicians... It is equally obvious that different branches of mathematics require different aptitudes... subjects that appeal to theory-builders are, at the moment, much more fashionable." Which aptitude is more fruitful likely depends on how much a field is objectively amenable to unification, and on its maturity. Economics and sociology are low on both.

In this example, there is a secret, hidden belief: “Affording the individual more control over expenditure decisions will afford the individual more freedom.” This is not necessarily true. For example: a landlord might increase rent to swallow UBI, but cannot increase rent to swallow food stamps.
For the college argument, there is an additional hidden belief: “Providing the resources necessary to attend college should happen for the benefit of the citizen.” While education is often of benefit to the individual who learns stuff, it is also of benefit to wider society. Benefit to the individual might not be the motivation behind universal education, so having the resources spent in a more selfish manner might be seen as misappropriation.
Widely-applicable models do sometimes exist in the real world, but by their nature they're rare. When multiple disparate arguments converge on the same belief, that's often a symptom of the arguments sharing a common premise (even if that premise hasn't been explicitly stated).
In this case, the implicit belief is a particular form of economic liberalism, as described by writers such as Adam Smith. (The extent to which the real world resembles this model, and hence the extent to which the example arguments are valid, is out of scope of this answer.) Once this common belief is made explicit, I do not see any epistemic harm from the centralisation of the arguments.

@local Convergence of arguments "by coincidence" only occurs in mathematics, as far as I can tell. In the real world, arguments only converge if they first diverged. (Maybe I don't understand the question.)

So is the centralization neutral, or does it constitute an increase in explanatory scope and thus an epistemic positive, and what conditions would change that to become neutral/negative?  I'm not sure I see that multiple disparate arguments rarely converge on the same belief; doesn't that happen every time a proposition is believed for multiple reasons?

I could make disparate arguments that it's not snowing outside my house based on the Weather Channel, the absence of frost on my window, and the fact that it's summer.  Each piece of evidence at a trial could be construed as an argument for the defendant's guilt.  In debates over X, speakers almost always construct multiple arguments for X.  This seems to be normal.

Finally, yeah, The College Argument and so forth aren't meant to be comprehensive arguments.  The most glaring weakness might be that they aren't even valid (I argued that UBI is better than vouchers but not that the two are jointly exhaustive of the ways to provide the relevant resources).  They're not my arguments, they're Alice's!  :P

The original hedgehog and fox idea was an example of sweeping polarisation. Centralising ideas can be very helpful in showing the relationship between what might otherwise considered to be entirely different things. For example, the idea that matter is made of protons, neutrons and electrons has helped us understand many of the properties of matter in a way that was impossible when we thought every element was separate. The fault you have identified in your question is that of applying a big idea without considering whether it is applicable, which is a form of bigotry.
Clearly, centralising ideas are a benefit when applied correctly, and a source of error when not.
It seems reasonable to me that humans have evolved to develop and rely on centralising concepts because their selective use is better than trying to figure out everything from first principles. But the key word there is selective. It’s like the difference between an off the peg suit and a bespoke one. You can get the off the peg suit for much less and you don’t have to wait for it to be made, but you still have to check that it fits.

@local cheers! In my case it’s meant to be a humorous persona I adopt just for this site. I am a genial idiot in real life- if you doubt it, try a free read of one of my books on Amazon!
